# Docker Windows Grant Access to Build Agent User

Tags: docker, go-cd

I'm trying to configure a GoCD agent to build my projects using Docker.  Originally my GoAgents ran as SYSTEM, because that is the default install on Windows, but I found that created problems during the build (I was getting weird failures due to $env:TEMP not being defined or being defined in a weird place).

I switched my go agents to a local account and granted account rights to run as a service.  This worked well until I tried to build docker images.  I have a script that works perfectly as my user but fails when running as the GoCD agent.

> error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.32/build?buildargs=%7B%22EngineDir%22%3A%22C%3A%5C%5CInfinity%22%2C%22ImageVersion%22%3A%222.0.0%22%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=29985a28e57e1f1b4fa8950cfa0f747b4c2680fa5f4fcb3643f68b4595825651&shmsize=0&t=invoke-infinity%3Alatest&t=invoke-infinity%3A2.0.0&target=&ulimits=null: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

I've tried adding the user to docker-users group but that doesn't appear to help.  I've tried following this article http://dille.name/blog/2017/11/29/using-the-docker-named-pipe-as-a-non-admin-for-windowscontainers/ but get and error saying Docker Windows doesn't support "hosts".

Does anybody have any way for a non-admin user on Windows to run docker build?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed in Docker for Windows version 18.03.0-ce.  Basically this version creates a local group called docker-users, who all have access to the pipe.  Simply add the desired users as members of that group, happy days!

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-win59-2018-03-26

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1732

Answer (score 0):

So the best answer (that I got) to this question is that I added a DOCKER_HOST environment variable for the account in question to use the a tcp connection.

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

I had to edit the 'C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json' file and add a "host".

```
{
  ...
  "hosts": [
    "npipe://",
    ...
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"

  ]
}
```

Once this was set the account was able to make calls to the docker engine via the CLI.

**Warning:** This is potentially insecure, Docker warns that this can open you up to remote code execution.  Not sure on the exact details of how, but for me the risk is minimal and I am willing to wear it.

**Additional:** I was able to get it working using the named pipe \.\pipe\docker_engine by creating a C# program that altered the SecurityDescriptor of the named pipe.  However, I discarded this as a viable solution because it needed to run every time the engine was started/stopped and was far to brittle for my liking

Comment: I have opened a feature request for this on docker for windows.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1732